# send email in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

In between the head and body I have :

```
<script language="C#" runat="server"> 

private void sendmail(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        try
        {

            MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage();
            mailObj.From = "no-reply@domain.be";
            mailObj.To = "nick@domain.be";
            mailObj.Subject = "Email via site ";
            mailObj.Body = "Dit is een email verstuurd via ASP.net .";
            //mailObj.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;
            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.one.com";
            SmtpMail.Send(mailObj);
            Response.Write("Email werd succesvol vestuurd");
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Response.Write("Email werd niet verstuurd: " + x.Message);
        }
    } 
    </script>
```

and in my body I have

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
```

But no email is being send, why not ??

Comment: Do you get some error in your catch clause?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Not enough information to be able to answer this. Does it throw an error? Have you checked the credentials? Is your mail server down? Firewall running?

Comment: Exception message and stack trace if any, please.

Comment: first: have configure your application to send email?   second: where are you calling the sendmail method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to trigger the sendmail method. There's nothing in your code that calls it.

You could have a button on your markup that invokes `sendEmail` when it is clicked.

For example:

```
<asp:button id="btnSend" OnClick="sendmail" runat="server" Text="Send" />
```

Also, [SmtpMail is obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.aspx). Use [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Comment: <asp:button id="btnSend" OnClick="sendmail" runat="server" Text="Send"  />  works;

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any authentication set for your SMTP server.

You may want to consider the newer 'SmtpClient' class instead. Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I will virtually guarantee you that either that smtp server does not exist, or you are not passing proper credentials.  If you have a GMail account, try with the following code, which will authenticate against and mail using GMail's SMTP server.  Once that is working, work back until you are properly authenticating against your own.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.Timeout = 3000;
client.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;

System.Net.NetworkCredential myCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
     "Your@emailhere.com"
     "YourPasswordHere"
                "");


client.Credentials = myCreds;
client.EnableSsl = true;

client.Send(message);
```